# Update row in sheet2 using sheet1 with primary column key in both the sheets

Tags: excel, power-automate

I would like to create power automate job .the flow is as follows-

Read the 'Integrator' values from Sheet1 and the 'Email' values corresponding to that 'Integrator'
Go to Sheet 2 .
Check for the 'Integrator' value in Sheet 2 and wherever the 'Integrator' value of Sheet 2 is matching with the 'Integrator' value of Sheet 1, update the email address in Sheet 2 from Sheet1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help unblock you but won't code/work for you :-).